# What is the point of "stderr" in Python?

Tags: python, error-handling, stdout, stdin, stderr

I'm a programming newbie and I'm trying to understand how `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` work. As I understand it, `stdout` and `stderr` are two different places where we can direct output from programs. I guess I don't understand what's the point of having a second "stream" of output just for errors with `stderr`? Why not have errors on the regular `stdout`? What does having errors on `stderr` allow me to do (basically why is `stderr` useful)?

Comment: You may want to ignore stdout but not stderr.  Separating the streams allows you to do just that, whether logging, parsing program output, etc.

Comment: Wiki: 'Standard error is another output stream typically used by programs to output error messages or diagnostics. It is a stream independent of standard output and can be redirected separately. This solves the semipredicate problem[...]' The point of stderr is to not guess but know what is output and what's an error code.

Comment: It is a matter of convenience and coherence, it is not the same an info to your users and a crash message

Comment: Actually I can't see any specifics of this question to Python, it's pretty much the same concept, independent of the programming lanuage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two "points" to supporting distinct stout and stderr streams:

1. When you are writing applications that can be chained together (e.g. using pipelines) you don't want the "normal" output to get mixed up with errors, warnings, debug info and other "chit chat".  Mixing them in the same stream would make life difficult for the next program in the chain / pipeline.

   Example:

   ```
   $ cat some-file | grep not
   $ echo $?
   ```

   If the `cat` command did not write its error messages to stderr, then the `grep` command would see a `"file not found"` message if `"some-file"` did not exist.  It would then (incorrectly) match on the "not", and set the return code for the pipeline incorrectly.  Constructing pipelines that coped with this sort of thing would be *hellishly difficult*.
2. Separate stdout and stderr streams have been support in (at least) UNIX and UNIX-like system since ... umm ... the 1970's.  And they are part of the POSIX standard.  If a new programming language's runtime libraries did not support this, then it would be considered to be crippled; i.e. unsuitable for writing production quality applications.

   (In the history of programming languages, Python is still relatively new.)

However, nobody is forcing to write your applications to use stderr for its intended purpose.  (Well ... maybe your future co-workers will :-) )

Comment: Technically, the language's runtime doesn't have to support it. The process (under the POSIX model, anyway) will find that it has two files open for writing when it starts. Whether or not the language provides a default binding for either or both file descriptors is a matter of convenience, not correctness.

Comment: Correct.  Technically it doesn't.  However, I for one would **flat out refuse** to use any modern PL that got this wrong ... for anything other than toy programs.  (Languages that fly in the face of convention .... for no good reason ... don't tend to survive.)

Comment: My point is, even if Python didn't provide `sys.stdout`, you could define it yourself with `stdout = open(1, "w")`. This isn't something provided by Python, but by the platform on which your Python implementation runs.

Comment: (Although, at some point, I guess the language has to provide *some* facility for accessing inherited file descriptors, so I'll concede that point.)

Comment: Hypothetically.  But you are assuming that you could do `open(1, "w")`.  For example, you couldn't do that in a language that didn't expose `fd` values as integers.  For example, Java.  But this is hypothetical because Python *does* support stderr.  And my **real** point is that a PL that didn't support stderr properly would not survive.

Answer (score 1):

In UNIX (and Linux, and other Posix-compatible systems) programs are often combined with pipes, so that one program takes the output of another one as input. If you would mix normal output and error information, every program would need to know how to treat diagnostic info from its pipe data producer differently from normal data. In practice, that is impossible due to the large number of program combinations.
By writing error information to stderr, each program makes it possible for the user to get this info without needing to filter it out of the data stream intended to be read by the next program in the pipe.

Comment: Pipes are just one of many redirection operations. I vaguely recall `cat nosuchfile >stdout` is even older than pipes.